# Generating and re-using unique, sequential, positive integers

Tags: c++, performance

In the past, I've often encountered the following problem and so far my go-to solution was to combine a counter with a hashtable (with open-addressing).

The only operations I need to implement are the following:

- next: generates a new integer or re-uses a previously freed one
- free: frees a previously generated integer
- size: returns the number of generated integers (excluding those who have been freed and not yet re-used)

Here's some working code that I use *very* often when this case pops up.

```cpp
class IdGenerator
{
    typedef std::uint64_t Id;

public:
    IdGenerator():
        total_ids_(0)
    {
    }

    Id next()
    {
        Id id;
        if (available_ids_.empty())
        {
            id = total_ids_;
            ++total_ids_;
        }
        else
        {
            auto it = available_ids_.begin();
            id = *it;
            available_ids_.erase(it);
        }
        return id;
    }

    void free(Id id)
    {
        available_ids_.insert(id);
    }

    Id size() const
    {
        return total_ids_ - available_ids_.size();
    }

private:
    std::unordered_set<Id> available_ids_; // usually, I use open-adressing here
    Id total_ids_;
};
```

While this code generally brings good performance, I've always wondered if there was a faster way of doing this.

Comment: If the code works correctly, and you only want to improve upon it: [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better place for such a question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about improving working code belong on CodeReview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip!

Comment: There's an old Vulcan proverb: "there's only one way to eat plomik soup."  There are not very many different ways to keep track of, and reuse, a particular resource. And just like there's only one way to add two numbers, using the `+` operator, there's just pretty much only one way to do this.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That's pretty much my state of mind on this question, I was more interested in obscure solutions that a pragmatic working one. :)

Comment: @Jean-MarieComets: Have you ever looked up how `malloc` is implemented? That seems potentially related.

Comment: `std::vector` (or `std::stack`)  seems sufficient (instead of the `unordered_set`).